# Proxy redirect errors with Nginx, Docker, Gunicorn, and Flask

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, https, gunicorn

I am using Flask, MariaDB, Nginx, Gunicorn, and Docker to host my webpage. I am using 4 separate docker containers (Flask + let's encrypt, Nginx, Gunicorn, and MariaDB) and the website is completely functional, connecting through https for all requests, but when redirecting via:

`return redirect(url_for('main.home'))`

the address does not resolve as

https://mywebsite.com/home

but instead resolves as the name of my gunicorn service, specified in my docker-compose.yml file:

gunicornservice/home

Note, my Flask app is a Blueprint() named 'main'. The locations specified in the url_for() calls are the names of the routes functions specified for 'main':

```
@main.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

I've tried editing the config file for nginx, as I believe this is where the solution lies due to this likely being a forwarding issue. I found slightly similar posts on SO, one of which referenced using _external=True as a second argument in url_for(), but this only resolved the address as 
mywebsite.com/home, which gave the same error,

"This site can’t be reached

gunicornservice’s server IP address could not be found.

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

My Nginx config file:

```
events { }

http {

    upstream upstream-web {
        server jonathanolson.us;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name gunicornservice;

        location / {
            root /NHL-Project/flasksite/static;
            proxy_pass http://gunicornservice:8000;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jonathanolson.us/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jonathanolson.us/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    }

    server {
        if ($host = jonathanolson.us) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name jonathanolson.us;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
}
```

I expect the results from a call to

```
return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
```

to return the URL:

"https://mywebsite.com/home"

but instead, it returns the URL:

"gunicornservice/home"

How can I make a call to redirect(url_for()) return the correct pages of my site, such as https://mywebsite.com/home?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue as described in this post, but I had to rely on different solution.

In my docker-compose file I set the nginx ports as follows.

```
 nginx:
   ports:
   - 1337:80
```

When the redirect command was called,

```
redirect(url_for('main.home'))
```

it forwarded to http://localhost/requested_uri

not to http://localhost:1337/requested_uri as I would have suspected.

The solution was to change the host definition in the nginx.config file.

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
```

was changed to:

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
```

The difference is that $host returns $http_host lowercase and without the port number.

Using $http_host solved the redirect issue for for me.

Comment: great call, was trying to debug this for hours. this fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, setting [SERVER_NAME](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/#SERVER_NAME) will help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in another post on SO. After plugging around more in my code, I got a 400 error, stating "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port", which led me to this SO post: [Dealing with nginx 400 "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8768946/9217197)

In this post, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55029648/9217197) explains how to insert a configuration specification that will forward that http request correctly into https.